# Operating on two dataframes with a unified index

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two .csv files that I am operating by loading into two different data frames (`df_A` and `df_B`). Operations are for example deducting one column from one another column in the second data frame. All data is keyed by a category and thus I am assuming that the following can work if the underlying index remains the same.

```
df_result["R"] = pd.to_numeric(df_B["B"].str.replace('%', '')) - pd.to_numeric(df_A["A"].str.replace('%', ''))
```

Each file has the same number of rows, but how can I ensure that the ordering remains the same when accessing `df_B["B"]`? I have tried to set the index with `set_index("Category", inplace = True)`, but later on operations that access `df_A["Category"]` fail with the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Line'
```

This occurs when I am trying to set a brand new data frame to use the same values, presumably because this is an index.

```
df_result["Category"] = df_A["Category"]
```

Is there a smarter way of creating a new data frame to store the results generated from dataframes `A` and `B`?

What is the best way of ensuring that rows in frame A relate to the very same row in frame B? Without `set_index`, am I just taking this for granted?

Comment: Hi, why don't you sort both dataframes by appending `.sort_values(by=['Category'])`?